# What does [6/10]-611 stand for?

Tags: analysis, engines, notation, terminology

I am using Chess for Android app by Aart Bik. Fairly easy to use and understand (and difficult to beat).

I get these numbers displayed below the noted moves and I think these are analysis symbols giving a summary of current position in terms of who is likelier to win. One example is in the question. Other examples are: [4/7]3, [3/7]95, etc.

Can someone interpret these numbers into English?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the online manual for the app](http://www.aartbik.com/MISC/amenu.html),

> After each engine's move, the output `[d/s]eval` indicates a search depth d, a selective search depth s, and an evaluation in centipawns eval from white's perspective. For instance, the output `[4/8]-103` indicates that the engine searched 4 plies ahead, with some variations even 8 plies ahead, and thinks that black is ahead by about a pawn.